# Incremental Static Regeneration, why is my "revalidate" field refreshing every time regardless of the given delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am following the example from: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration.

When I set the `revalidate: 60 * 10` field, I expect:

> The message does NOT change within 10 minutes when I keep hitting the refresh button.

However, with my code below, what happened is:

> The message changes EVERY time I hit the refresh button.

Here is my code stripping to the minimum:

```
export default function Home({ message }) {
    return <h1>{message}</h1>; <<<<<<<<<<< shows new value every time
};
export const getStaticProps = () => {
  return {
    props: {
      message: new Date().toISOString(), <<<<<<< runs every time regardless
    },
    revalidate: 60 * 10, <<<<<<<< I want it to cache for 10 minutes
  };
};
export const getStaticPaths = () => {
  return {
    fallback: 'blocking',
    paths: [],
  };
};
```

I tried this with Next.js `v12.3.2` and Next.js `v13.2.4`, and it produced the same behavior. Did I misunderstand how the `revalidate` works? Or did I miss something in the configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As they say on the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration), *"Next.js allows you to create or update static pages after you’ve built your site"*. After you’ve built your site is the word to emphasize.

If you want to test it, run `npm run build`, then `npm run start`, and visit the given URL. You will see it in action.